# Getting buttons to be on the same line

Tags: css

I've created a page that has a list of addresses next to each other. The problem I'm having is that I'm not getting my buttons to be on the same line. So what I would like is that the buttons will always be on the same line.

Here is my codepen [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MxZwyQ)

and here is my code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <form action="http://laravel-site.test/account/addresses-radio/4" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="6cR6PuL173IvCG1dXwEDwybbI5BFxtMlbAeXfPwz">                                        
            <div class="form-check">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="address_option" id="address_4" checked="">
                <label for="address_4" class="form-check-label">
                    Compex 1 <br>
                    Address 1 <br>
                    Suburb 1 <br>
                    City 1 <br>
                    Provice 1 <br>
                    Code 1 <br>
                </label>
            </div>
        </form>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-1">
                <div class="edit-button">
                    <a href="http://laravel-site.test/account/create-address" class="btn btn-primary">Add Address</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <form action="http://laravel-site.test/account/addresses-radio/5" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="6cR6PuL173IvCG1dXwEDwybbI5BFxtMlbAeXfPwz">                                        
            <div class="form-check">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="address_option" id="address_5">
                <label for="address_5" class="form-check-label">
                    Address 2 <br>
                    Suburb 2 <br>
                    City 2 <br>
                    Provice 2 <br>
                    Code 2 <br>
                </label>
            </div>
        </form>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-1">
                <div class="edit-button">
                    <a href="http://laravel-site.test/account/create-address" class="btn btn-primary">Add Address</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <form action="http://laravel-site.test/account/addresses-radio/6" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="6cR6PuL173IvCG1dXwEDwybbI5BFxtMlbAeXfPwz">                                        
            <div class="form-check">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="address_option" id="address_6">
                <label for="address_6" class="form-check->label">
                    Compex 3 <br>
                    Address 3 <br>
                    Suburb 3 <br>
                    City 3 <br>
                    Provice 3 <br>
                    Code 3 <br>
                </label>
            </div>
        </form>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-1">
                <div class="edit-button">
                    <a href="http://laravel-site.test/account/create-address" class="btn btn-primary">Add Address</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried things like `position: absolute` but that didn't work out as how I would like it

Answer (score 0):

You can add `flexbox` to the column container and align the items to the end of the each column. I also set the box not to wrap (optional).

```html
<div class="row d-flex flex-nowrap align-items-end">
  …
</div>
```

Demo

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row d-flex flex-nowrap align-items-end">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <form action="http://laravel-site.test/account/addresses-radio/4" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="6cR6PuL173IvCG1dXwEDwybbI5BFxtMlbAeXfPwz">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="address_option" id="address_4" checked="">
        <label for="address_4" class="form-check-label">
     Compex 1 <br>
     Address 1 <br>
     Suburb 1 <br>
     City 1 <br>
     Provice 1 <br>
     Code 1 <br>
    </label>
      </div>
    </form>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-1">
        <div class="edit-button">
          <a href="http://laravel-site.test/account/create-address" class="btn btn-primary">Add Address</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <form action="http://laravel-site.test/account/addresses-radio/5" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="6cR6PuL173IvCG1dXwEDwybbI5BFxtMlbAeXfPwz">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="address_option" id="address_5">
        <label for="address_5" class="form-check-label">
     Address 2 <br>
     Suburb 2 <br>
     City 2 <br>
     Provice 2 <br>
     Code 2 <br>
    </label>
      </div>
    </form>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-1">
        <div class="edit-button">
          <a href="http://laravel-site.test/account/create-address" class="btn btn-primary">Add Address</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <form action="http://laravel-site.test/account/addresses-radio/6" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="6cR6PuL173IvCG1dXwEDwybbI5BFxtMlbAeXfPwz">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="address_option" id="address_6">
        <label for="address_6" class="form-check->label">
     Compex 3 <br>
     Address 3 <br>
     Suburb 3 <br>
     City 3 <br>
     Provice 3 <br>
     Code 3 <br>
    </label>
      </div>
    </form>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-1">
        <div class="edit-button">
          <a href="http://laravel-site.test/account/create-address" class="btn btn-primary">Add Address</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your html in this way to get all the buttons in same line.
Put all the buttons in the same `row` with class `col-lg-4` outside the main row container. Here is the link for running [stackblitz](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/moaebm).

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <form action="http://laravel-site.test/account/addresses-radio/4" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="6cR6PuL173IvCG1dXwEDwybbI5BFxtMlbAeXfPwz">                                        
            <div class="form-check">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="address_option" id="address_4" checked="">
                <label for="address_4" class="form-check-label">
                    Compex 1 <br>
                    Address 1 <br>
                    Suburb 1 <br>
                    City 1 <br>
                    Provice 1 <br>
                    Code 1 <br>
                </label>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <form action="http://laravel-site.test/account/addresses-radio/5"         method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token"        value="6cR6PuL173IvCG1dXwEDwybbI5BFxtMlbAeXfPwz">                                     
            <div class="form-check">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input"        name="address_option" id="address_5">
                <label for="address_5" class="form-check-label">
                    Address 2 <br>
                    Suburb 2 <br>
                    City 2 <br>
                    Provice 2 <br>
                    Code 2 <br>
                </label>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <form action="http://laravel-site.test/account/addresses-radio/6" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="6cR6PuL173IvCG1dXwEDwybbI5BFxtMlbAeXfPwz">                                        
            <div class="form-check">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="address_option" id="address_6">
                <label for="address_6" class="form-check->label">
                    Compex 3 <br>
                    Address 3 <br>
                    Suburb 3 <br>
                    City 3 <br>
                    Provice 3 <br>
                    Code 3 <br>
                </label>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>                                          
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="edit-button">
                    <a href="http://laravel-site.test/account/create-address" class="btn btn-primary">Add Address</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="edit-button">
                    <a href="http://laravel-site.test/account/create-address" class="btn btn-primary">Add Address</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="edit-button">
                    <a href="http://laravel-site.test/account/create-address" class="btn btn-primary">Add Address</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```